# python regex: to match space character or end of string

Tags: python, regex

I want to match space chars or end of string in a text.

```
import re


uname='abc'
assert re.findall('@%s\s*$' % uname, '@'+uname)
assert re.findall('@%s\s*$' % uname, '@'+uname+'  '+'aa')
assert not re.findall('@%s\s*$' % uname, '@'+uname+'aa')
```

The pattern is not right.
How to use python?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`\s*$` is incorrect: this matches "zero or more spaces *followed by* the end of the string", rather than "one or more spaces *or* the end of the string".

For this situation, I would use
`(?:\s+|$)` (inside a raw string, as others have mentioned).
The `(?:)` part is just about separating that subexpression so that the | operator matches the correct fragment and no more than the correct fragment.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
assert re.findall('@%s\\s*$' % uname, '@'+uname)
```

You must escape the `\` character if you don't use raw strings.

It's a bit confusing, but stems from the fact that `\` is a meta character for both the python interpreter and the `re` module.

Comment: sorry but second not passed

Comment: @whi, the second one didn't pass because `@abc  aa` doesn't have match the pattern of white spaces followed by the end of the string. See Kampu's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use [raw strings](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html).

```
assert re.findall(r'@%s\s*$' % uname, '@'+uname)
```

Otherwise the use of `\` as a special character in regular strings conflicts with its use as a special character in regular expressions.

But this assertion is impossible to fail.  Of course, a string consisting of nothing but "@" plus the contents of the variable `uname` is going to match a regular expression of "@" plus `uname` plus optional (always empty) whitespace and then the end of the string.  It's a tautology.  I suspect you are trying to check for something else?