# regular expression starts with @ and ends with a space

Tags: ios

Write a regular expression that starts with @ and ends with a space. There may be multiple spaces in the middle, matching only the last one。

for example:
@xbadfd @dsfsdfssdf 113 asdf @222

There are three matches:

```
@xbadfd
@dsfsdfssdf 113 asdf
@222
```

Comment: Can you show the code you have attempted? Something like this could get you started  "^@\s+|$".

Comment: This might help too.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16519744/python-regex-to-match-space-character-or-end-of-string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would phrase the regex as:

```regex
@.*?(?=[ ]@|$)
```

### Demo

This pattern says to match:

```regex
@           leading @
.*?         followed all content up to the NEAREST
(?=[ ]@|$)  space followed by another starting @, or the end of the input
            (but don't consume this, just lookahead and assert)
```